# Using Mysql/Ajax to populate Form using value from Input Fields

Tags: mysql, json, ajax

Am trying to populate a reasonably large form (40 odd fields) with values from a MySQL database.

I have no problems creating the JSON array from the query.

```
  echo json_encode($row);
```

What I would like to achieve is difficult to find out from other posts etc and it may be impossible to do.

What I wish to do...

Use 2 Input Fields that both must be filled correctly before populating the rest of the form.

So

FIELD1 = Membership No

FIELD 2 = Drivers License No.

(A quick sort of Security Check)

So if FIELD1 AND FIELD2 equals values in the database, then populate the rest of the form.

Nothing happens UNTIL BOTH fields are filled.

My mysql query is a straight forward -  WHERE FIELD1='value1' AND FIELD2='value2'

Is this at all possible to do?

The other approach I was contemplating was to somehow use AJAX to update the mysql query with the input values, then refresh the page. The query would change to EG WHERE FIELD1='56779' AND FIELD2='Q16987999'

Comment: can you share the code what you written for the same ?

Comment: Using the example at https://gist.github.com/webaware/4048580 as a start point as it seems the closest to what I am after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not pursuing this any further.  Too complicated when I can just create a "Login" style form using Member No and Drivers Licence as the Username and password, then POST these values to the SQL Query on the next page.

Then a simple SELECT query to populate all necessary fields with mysqli_fetch_assoc